# How to specify a target at WikiMiniAtlas

Tags: url, wikimedia-commons, openstreetmap

I want to link to a particular location with the map of Wikimedia pictures at https://wma.wmflabs.org/

This map has a `Center on target` button, so I guess there is a way to specify a target latitude/longitude via the URL.

What is this webapp's URL syntax for specifying a latitude/longitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the URL pattern:

```
https://wma.wmflabs.org/iframe.html?wma=
 <latitude>_<longitude>_<width>_<height>_commons_<zoomlevel>_<language>
 &globe=Earth&lang=<language>
```

`<width>` and `<height>` seem to have no effect.

Example around the White House:

https://wma.wmflabs.org/iframe.html?wma=38.8977_-77.0365_700_500_commons_14_en&globe=Earth&lang=en